# Set fire to something VS Set something on fire

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> - These guys **set fire to an old house**.

> - These guys **set an old house on fire**.

- Is there any difference in meaning in the two sentences above?

Answer (score 2):

*On fire* is usually used of a building or vehicle which is burning, while you can *set fire to* anything combustible, including an object small enough to hold. So, in the case of a house, there is no difference in meaning.